# Given $V=U_1\oplus U_2$, prove that a projection onto $U_1$ is self-adjoint if and only if $U_1\perp U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, direct-sum

Let $V$ be an inner product space that is an inner direct sum
$U_1 \oplus U_2$ of its subspaces $U_1, U_2$, and let $T: V → V$ be the projection to $U_1$
along $U_2$.

Prove that $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if $U_1 ⊥ U_2$.

Honestly, I have no clue how to approach this question. help me out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ is a direct sum, every element $u \in V$ has a unique expression $u=u_1+u_2$ with $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in U_2$.  The map $T$ is the one which satisfies $T(u_1+u_2) = u_1$.

Suppose $T$ is self-adjoint.  We want to show that $\langle u_1, u_2\rangle = 0$ for any $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in U_2$.  Compute: $$\langle u_1, u_2\rangle = \langle T(u_1), u_2\rangle = \langle u_1, T(u_2) \rangle.$$  But what is $T(u_2)$?

Conversely, suppose $U_1 \perp U_2$.  If $u_1, w_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2, w_2 \in U_2$, then we want to compute: $$\langle T(u_1+u_2), w_1+w_2\rangle = \langle u_1, w_1+w_2\rangle = \langle u_1, w_1\rangle + \langle u_1, w_2 \rangle = \langle u_1, w_1 \rangle.$$

Similarly, $\langle u_1+u_2, T(w_1+w_2) \rangle = \langle u_1, w_1 \rangle.$  What can you conclude about $T$?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am guessing that $T=T^*$, and $T(u_2)$ would be just 0?

Comment: Right, because we've shown that $\langle Tv, w\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle$ for all $v, w$.